# Java Big Decimal Half Even Bug?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I'm trying to specifically use this value

`new BigDecimal("23.025").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);`

The output is 23.02, but should be 23.03. Is it a bug?

Just for curiosity `DecimalFormat("#####0,00");` also does not work

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Why do you believe it should be `23.03`? The last digit is `3`, which is not an even number. What do you believe the `EVEN` part of `HALF_EVEN` means, and why do you believe that?

Comment: When I run into similar issues I always assume that the bug is in my understanding and not in Java itself, and I am  be right 99.99% of the time. I'm betting that your odds are similar.

Comment: @Andreas because `new BigDecimal("23.035").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);` return 23.04. Mathematically 0 to 4 goes down and 5 to 9 goes up

Comment: @LeonardoSilva What else should it return? `23.03`? That's not an even digit. You do know what **even** means, right? The opposite of **odd**. 3 is odd, 4 is even.

Comment: *"Mathematically 0 to 4 goes down and 5 to 9 goes up"* That is called the [`HALF_UP`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP) rounding mode: *"Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round **up**."* --- You're asking for [`HALF_EVEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN): *"Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the **even** neighbor."*

Comment: Maybe you should **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN), where all this is documented, with nice tables showing how the rounding works.

Answer (score 10):

`RoundingMode#HALF_EVEN` *JavaDoc* says

> Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" **unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even
>   neighbor**

In your case the `even` neighbor is `02`.
JavaDoc is important! Read it, always.
For `RoundingMode`, it can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) (Java 8 version).

Comment: But why `new BigDecimal("23.035").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);` return 23.04?

Comment: @LeonardoSilva because the *even* number is 04.

Comment: To 23.025 the even neighbor is the floor and to 23.035 the even neighbor is the ceil?This is my doubt

Comment: @LeonardoSilva Because `23.035` has two neighbors with scale 2: `23.03` and `23.04`, and `23.04` is the **even** one. --- Similarly, `23.025` has two neighbors with scale 2: `23.02` and `23.03`, and `23.02` is the **even** one.

Comment: @LeonardoSilva there is no *floor* or *ceil* in this case, forget them. There is *even* and *odd* here

Comment: @Leonardo: it will round up or round down, depending on which neighbour is even (i.e. ends in digit 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8). This is called **banker's rounding**, although bankers actually don't round that way.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Interesting Rudy! Didn't know about this algorithm (btw, you must have edited/re-posted your comment a dozen times minimum :P)

Comment: @LppEdd: well, only three times now. But the last one was too long and repeated what others had already said. ;-)

Comment: Not sure if/when it is going to happen, but I sure will notify you then.